# CodeIgniter: Preventing row_array() vs row() typo's?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Twice now I've mistakenly used row() instead of row_array() when fetching a single row result. Usually, it goes unchecked without any warning messages. 15-30 minutes later I finally notice the issue; doh doh!

Does anyone have any good suggestions as to ways to prevent this mistake. The object format doesn't throw a PHP warning, but - of course - the code doesn't work when you expect an array from a model method.

I accidentally used:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row();
}
```

Which should instead be:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

I thought about overriding the row() database method and adding in a log_message() statement that would at least let me know (on debug level) that I'm using the object format, instead of the much more typical (for my code) format.

Comment: Make the mistake about 5 more times. Then you'll never do it again. Seriously.

Comment: Overriding the core database class method seems a bit overkill...  just don't type the wrong thing...

Comment: I agree with Jonathan M, but if you are really looking for a way to avoid this without overriding the core, you could create a snippet that expands `row()` to `row_array()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way to "prevent" is pretty much learn over the documentation again so you can keep a common habit of using which function.

You can note yourself, if you are going to return **multiple** records, use the `row_array()`, for a **singular** record, use the `row()` function.

Remember, don't speed type your code, proofread your code step by step before continuing.

Overriding the original function is bad practice, using the `row()` function is useful when retrieving a singular record, so don't do this.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The decision between row() and row_array() is whether you want to deal with the row as an instantiated object or as an associative array, not whether there is one or multiple rows. The difference between that is result_array() or row_array(), which both have result() and row() counterparts.

Comment: I concur with user548084.  This answer is misleading.  `row()` returns a flat object.  `row_array()` returns a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

How do you avoid making data-type errors in your CodeIgniter model methods?  Simple, declare your methods' return data type.

```
// returns null or an object
public function getFlatObject(int $id): ?object
{
    return $this->db->get_where("your_table", ['id' => $id])->row();
}

// unconditionally returns an array
public function getFlatArray(int $id): array
{
    return $this->db->get_where("your_table", ['id' => $id])->row_array();
}
```

If your return data does not match the declared type(s) (after `:`), then php is going to generate errors for you.

---

Let's take this opportunity to clear up any confusion...

- If you call either `row()` or `row_array()` and your sql logic affords the possibility of more than one row of data -- then you are only going to get the first row of the result set.
- If you call `row()` but there are no rows in the result set, you will have a return value of `null`.
- If you call `row_array()` but there are no rows in the result set, you will receive an empty array as the return value.
- Hence, `row()` may return an iterable or non-iterable data type; whereas `row_array()` can ALWAYS be safely passed directly into an iterator (like `foreach()` or `array_map()`) -- it just might not having anything to iterate.

Comment: @jjw given that the accepted answer is providing misinformation, you may wish to re-evaluate where the green tick is on this page.

Answer (score 0):

row() returns object type, and row_array() returns array.
So it is better in parsing the data of row data in DB when using row_array.